Dnd-kit: how to introduce delay in collision detection for swappable grid
When implementing swappable grid with dnd-kit (great lib, btw), I'm facing the following issue: there is a lot of not needed movement. It looks like this, check cell number 7:

How can this issue be avoided? Probably it can be done by introducing some delay in collision detection using custom collision detection algorithm, but I can't really get how exactly.

You can change collisionDetection in DndContext props
You can find it here:
https://docs.dndkit.com/api-documentation/context-provider#collision-detection
and here more info:
https://docs.dndkit.com/api-documentation/context-provider/collision-detection-algorithms
You can also go to dnd-kit files in node_modules and find there names of collisionDetection props:

I use this:
collisionDetection={closestCenter}

Thanks for the answer, that's exactly what I've tried with no luck. Maybe you know how it should be used in particular?

I will be difficult without knowing the rest of code. But the way I am using it is collisionDetection={closestCenter}
